# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' latin-1

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create an HTML Report for my unit Test Script, When i try to run the code, it is throwing, this error  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Below is the part of code, where it is showing error :-

```
if isinstance(o,str):
    # TODO: some problem with 'string_escape': it escape \n and mess up formating
    # uo = unicode(o.encode('string_escape'))
    uo = o.decode('latin-1')
else:
    uo = o 
if isinstance(e,str):
    # TODO: some problem with 'string_escape': it escape \n and mess up formating
    # ue = unicode(e.encode('string_escape'))
    ue = e.decode('latin-1')
else:
    ue = e

script = self.REPORT_TEST_OUTPUT_TMPL % dict(
    id = tid,
    output = saxutils.escape(uo+ue),
)
```

The above code is from `HTMLTestRunner.py` File. Please help in debugging this issue.

Comment: Correct method is decode not encode

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using python3 (because of the tag in your question)

In python3 there is no longer a `unicode` type, it is simply `str` - `str` is a text type, which is already unicode decoded, therefore, there is no longer a `decode` method for `str`.

For working with strings, there is the `bytes` type that has a `decode` method (`decode`-ing `bytes` return `str`, and `encode`-ing `str` returns `bytes`.

So from now on - instead of using `decode` when the type is `str`, use `decode` only if the type is `bytes`.

Meaning your code should look like this:

```
if isinstance(o,bytes):
    uo = o.decode('latin-1')
else:
    uo = o 
if isinstance(e,bytes):
    ue = e.decode('latin-1')
else:
    ue = e

script = self.REPORT_TEST_OUTPUT_TMPL % dict(
    id = tid,
    output = saxutils.escape(uo+ue),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for Helping me Dean,   after changing it to "bytes", i am facing error, in one of the  line 
 " self.stream.write(output.encode('utf8')) ", it says that,                              " TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes "  Please help me in, how to correct this error

Comment: @Santosh - On which line? It probably happens after this block of code, when writing the report to a file. (It is expecting a steam open with `wb` instead of `w`)

Comment: Thank You Dean, it started Working Now..:)